# Converting formula/equation in docx to html using docx4j

Tags: html, docx, equation, docx4j

I'm trying to convert docx containing equations to on Android. I came across docx4j which is great and tested the following sample (HtmlExporterNonXSTL):
https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/android/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/html/HtmlExporterNonXSLT.java

However I noticed that it doesn't handler equations well - if some symbol or number has some power and/or indices their position is alway in the middle e.g. 
`k_{n+1}^2 (latex format)`

is displayed as:

```
kn+12 (with 'n+12' having correct smaller font but they are both vertically aligned)
```

Is there any way to adjust CSS to handle powers and indices? (full formula conversion would be better but I guess it is not so easy). I'm new to docx4j but looks like somehow 
`handlePPr()`

method will need to be modified in `HtmlExporterNonXSLT` example. Before I would dive into it I thought about asking is it even possible to accomplish it (any way to obtain the offset property of a run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure: I'm docx4j project lead**

You're welcome to modify HtmlExporterNonXSLT in order to fix your particular example, but as you say, full formula conversion would be better.

Here are links to three prior posts on that subject (newest first):

- [math-equations-and-docx-to-html-conversion-not-working](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/math-equations-and-docx-to-html-conversion-not-working-t966.html)
- [need-to-handle-latex-equation](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/need-to-handle-latex-equation-t293.html)
- [math-expression-issue](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/math-expression-issue-t229.html)